# How to apply multiple image textures and bake them into 1 image

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I have tried searching the web have not found a clear solution to this.
What I would like to achieve is to apply multiple image textures to a model

https://i.stack.imgur.com/67UNe.jpg

and the model in blender

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4OkH.jpg

EDIT: the video basically says to install the node wrangler plugin in blender and then use ctrl + shift + T, in the node editor with the principled BSDF selected, to select all textures

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably this is what you need to start
Move to the minute  00:09:29

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMbc2e_SN_Y&feature=youtu.be

Hope that helps.

Good Luck

Comment: It's better to write the essential parts of the answer and have the link only as a reference, that way we can quickly see the solution here without having to go to an external site.